# Как вывести значение Cookies

Tags: php, cookie

Есть кукие name - 'n' и value - 'Win'. При просмотре кукие есть.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['n'])){  
     require('first.php');  
} else {  
     require('second.php');  
}
```

как только не пытался ни как не мог вытащить значение кукие в браузер, хотя запись в кукие происходит без всяких проблем. И еще вопрос, для того чтобы вывести значение кукие обязательно ли их вытаскивать в самом начале, или можно в теле самой страницы.
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_COOKIE['n'])){
    echo 'Кука уже установлена: '.$_COOKIE['n'];
}else{
    setcookie('n', 'Hello', time() + 3600);
    echo 'Добавлена новая печенька';
};
?>
```

Не знаю, что у вас могло не получится.
Доступ к кукам есть в любом месте.
Перед первым выводом только установка сookies, т.к. данные передаются в headers-заголовках

Comment: Может ли быть какие-то дополнительные настройки сервера. Я использую Apache для тестов. и возможно ли как-нибудь по-другому решить данный момент.

Comment: Да, пусть стоит учитывать, но это стало рутиной для веб-девов.
Пусть для всего домена - /
С учетом поддоменов - *.domainname.com